# Why api.fixer.io doesn't showing list of all currencies?

Tags: api, currency, fixer.io

I'm trying to access this API `https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD` but I have noticed that, it showing only 31 countries currency and I want all.

I googled it but doesn't getting any answer for this API.

**Below is the response :**

```
{"base":"USD","date":"2017-06-23","rates":{"AUD":1.3214,"BGN":1.7505,"BRL":3.3378,"CAD":1.3231,"CHF":0.97118,"CNY":6.8391,"CZK":23.536,"DKK":6.6564,"GBP":0.78587,"HKD":7.7998,"HRK":6.6258,"HUF":276.68,"IDR":13305.0,"ILS":3.5418,"INR":64.532,"JPY":111.3,"KRW":1137.7,"MXN":18.045,"MYR":4.288,"NOK":8.468,"NZD":1.3734,"PHP":50.226,"PLN":3.7877,"RON":4.0916,"RUB":59.669,"SEK":8.7443,"SGD":1.3869,"THB":33.945,"TRY":3.5116,"ZAR":12.936,"EUR":0.89501}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a currency converter app using that API and I don't know about any better resource for that.
 I think it provides limited currencies because fixer gets it's data from European central bank, which only provides those particular currencies. 
check here:
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html

Comment: Ok but does it safe to use in iOS app and Apple will allow app using this API?